# Scrape information from multiple URLs listed in a CSV using BeautifulSoup and then export these results to a new CSV file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a 45k+ rows CSV file, each one containing a different path of the same domain - which are structurally identical to each other - and every single one is clickable. I managed to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the title and content of each one and through the `print` function, I was able to validate the scraper. However, when I try to export the information gathered to a new CSV file, I only get the last URL's street name and description, and not all of them as I expected.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('URLs.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        site = requests.get(row['addresses']).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, 'lxml')
        StreetName = soup.find('div', class_='hist-title').text
        Description = soup.find('div', class_='hist-content').text
with open('OutputList.csv','w', newline='') as output:
    Header = ['StreetName', 'Description']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=Header)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'StreetName' : StreetName, 'Description' : Description})
```

How can the output CSV have on each row the street name and description for the respective URL row in the input CSV file?

Comment: You're not saving the data you scrape anywhere...? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Either write the StreetName and Description out to a string or a list as you go through. The reason you are only seeing the last is that you are overriding the previous one each time.

Comment: @guicalmeida, can you post a sample of your input CSV file? I can improve my answer a bit by knowing what you have on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open both files on the same level and then read and write on each iteration. Something like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('URLs.csv') as a, open('OutputList.csv', 'w') as b:

    reader = csv.reader(a)

    writer = csv.writer(b, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(['StreetName', 'Description'])

    # Assuming url is the first field in the CSV
    for url, *_ in reader:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.ok:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            street_name = soup.find('div', class_='hist-title').text.strip()
            description = soup.find('div', class_='hist-content').text.strip()
            writer.writerow([street_name, description])
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, accdias. I added a printscreen to the post.

 I managed to export the CSV, however I bumped into 2 minor problems: first, the texts's semicolon are being interpreted as new columns at the same line; the second is that the output CSV have the title on a row and the description below, instead of two columns.

Sorry if this all sound obvious, this is literally my first time coding. Regards!

Comment: No worries, @guicalmeida. Let me see if I can fix it. If possible, please update the question showing the results you got with my code and also, please do not post image of text, copy and paste the text instead.

Comment: Check the new version and see if that fixes the other problems, please. Description is going below because of embedded newlines on the text from the page. I've added `strip()` for the `soup` calls and it will take care of any newline at the beginning and at the end of the string but not of any embedded in the text. If the solution above still did not producing the result wanted, let me know and I will amend it.